# Problem with jQuery menu in IE6/7/8. Links disappear

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, menu, cross-browser, jquery-animate

I've got a bizarre problem with my menu for a site I'm making. And it's concerns - of course - Internet Explorer (all versions). When I move cursor over menu element  it's shows one time and then disappears. You can check this under IE here: [link to the site](http://www.toya.net.pl/cachaito/euromat)
After this every menu element's are not clickable :-[

PS. I just want to add, that instead of *.png background I tried *.jpg and *.gif with no result.

Ok. I've got menu.js

```
$('#nav a').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');},
    function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow');
});
```

in css there's:

```
body#start ul#nav {background: transparent url('../img/buttons_bckgd.png') no-repeat 0 0;}

#top_menu #nav li {float: left;}

#top_menu #nav li a {
   display: block;  
   height: 60px;
   margin-top: 7px;
   opacity: 0;
   }

.home {
   width: 163px;
   margin-left: 12px;
   }

.home:hover {background: url('../img/buttons_bckgd.png') no-repeat -12px -382px;}
```

html part is a pure standard:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a class="home" href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a class="offer" href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a class="gallery" href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a class="contact" href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas why  vanishes and how to solve this?

Comment: does it work in firefox?

Comment: Yes it works on Firefox/ Opera/ Chrome/ Safari etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, second attempt :-) I did some testing http://jsfiddle.net/7h6Vn/ which should work in all browsers. However the key CSS property that I needed to add to make it work in IE6 is the  `background-color: white;` line in the `#nav li a` rule. If you take that out then the hover animation is broken after the first time.

I only have IE6 so this may not solve the problem for all IE versions.

Edit: This seems to fix the hovering but you might have to play with setting the background-color to something different for your menu.

Also crediting the site that jogged my memory about the `background-color` fix - http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/09/02/how-to-make-cleartype-font-face-fonts-and-css-visual-filters-play-nicely-together/

Edit 2: OK, this http://jsfiddle.net/7h6Vn/1/ definitely works (mouse over the result area). I'm linking to your image to show the hover fade animation. Whilst playing around to get this working I also experienced the same problem as was [solved here](http://ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375646/jquery-animate-opacity-doesnt-work-properly-on-ie/1990708#1990708). One last point to note is that I needed to add the CSS opacity filter for IE which is non-standard, so you might want to put that in a separate IE specific CSS file.

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want but it was fun playing around with this nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

That is very weird. I set up an example for you based on your code. http://jsfiddle.net/Ruhley/emHFY/. It works for me on IE7, what about you?

Comment: Very, very strange. Your example works even on IE! I'll check rest of the my code :-/

Answer (score 0):

Can you place the code in the same page instead of a different script file.

Opening IE8 developer tools and debugging the menu.js script shows that when the mouse is hovered the second time, the code is not executed.

Comment: Hi! I've put code directly into index.php on top or just before </body> and the same result :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the event wireup only when the document is ready, something similar to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Do menu event wiring here...
});
```

...and add the script link include just before closing the body tag. It usually does the trick for me.

Comment: Sorry I did'nt write this, but $(document).ready(function() is originally in the code. I'll edit this right now.

Answer (score 0):

Is the DD_belatedPNG script interfering with the background image property? I know you said that you tried with different image types but have you tried removing the PNG fix script? This is not present in http://jsfiddle.net/Ruhley/emHFY/ which might explain why it works in that demo and not on your site.

Comment: Unfortunately DD_belatedPNG script is in conditional comment only for IE6 so in IE8 should not interfere.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the :hover style that's in the styles.css file. If I remove the jQuery menu code , then it works in IE8 but breaks down in other browsers.

Comment: I have added a second potential [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151853/problem-with-jquery-menu-in-ie6-7-8-links-disappear/5153765#5153765) in a different comment which is working for me in Firefox, Chrome and IE6.